# Is there any method for get current directory other than GetCurrentDirectory on c++?

Tags: c++, winapi

I used GetCurrentDirectory to get the current directory from c++. However, if it was run by the registry after a reboot, the current directory will appear as c://Windows//System32 instead of the true current directory.

my code:

```
wchar_t get_path[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectoryW(MAX_PATH, get_path);
```

Comment: why do you think that this is **not** the current directory?

Comment: What do you mean by "true current directory"?

Comment: Current Directory is per process, at the time of the call - so the call is returning the correct directory.

Comment: Not totally clear what you are trying to achive. If run by registry after boot, it is normal that the current directory is c:\windows\system32. Do you want to the folder of where your program is located?

Comment: Before C++17, there was nothing in standard C++ (so it was necessary to resort to implementation or system specific functions).   From C++17, there  is `std::current_path` (in `<filesystem>`).   `GetCurrentDirectory()` and related functions/macros are still part of the windows API.

Comment: Read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory). It returns the correct directory.

Comment: If this code is part of a dll, then it will return the directory path of the executable that has loaded this.

Comment: *"instead of the true current directory"* - What makes you think the system were playing tricks on you? That **is** the current working directory. It may not be what you expected, or what you need. First order is: Stop relying on the current working directory. Once you decided to do so, try phrasing the **real** problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @wan `GetCurrentDirectory` returns the current working directory of the calling process. It does so irrespective of the module that calls it. The current working directory is per-process state, making it virtually useless unless you control the *entirety* of the process.

Comment: No `c://Windows//System32` was actually the current working directory of your program that run after boot. The OS is not lying to you. Any other method would end up calling this function and return the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++17 provides [std::filesystem::current_path()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path), so the literal answer to your question is: Yes, C++ offers a different way to get the current working directory.

More to the point: C++ offers a different *interface*. Internally, it just calls into `GetCurrentDirectoryW`, and produces the same value.

So if `GetCurrentDirectory` doesn't work for you<sup>1</sup>, then nothing else will work for you either.

---

The *real* solution to the problem is to stop relying on the current directory. It is per-process state, and any thread in that process can change it at any time. Unless you **fully** control the process, there's absolutely no way to derive a reliable solution that relies on the current directory.

---

<sup>1</sup> *`GetCurrentDirectory` returns the correct value. What needs fixing is the expectations that are off.*